# Revit API. StorageType of ParameterElement

Tags: c#, revit-api

I need to create a filter in a Revit manner.
[image]

1. With `ParameterFilterUtilities.GetFilterableParametersInCommon` get common set of parameters for target categories. `GetFilterableParametersInCommon` returns a set of ids. There are 3 types are expected in returning: `BuiltinParameter` with Id < 0, and `SharedElementParameter` and `ParameterElement` with Id > 0 (`doc.GetElement(Id)`).
2. One of parameters for `ParameterElementFilter` creation is `FilterNumericRuleEvaluator` for numeric type or  `FilterStringRuleEvaluator` for string type.
3. Create proper `Evaluator` according the StorageType. For `BuiltinParameter` `doc.get_TypeOfStorage(<BuiltinParameter>)` works perfectly, but I cannot get `StorageType` for `ParameterElement` only `ParameterType`.

So is there any way to get to know which `Evaluator` type should be used for `ParameterElement`?

Answer (score 1):

Can't see the `StorageType` on the `ParameterElement` in [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup)?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for your help. I looked for Element parameter using ```RevitLookup```, and it seems has no ```StoageType``` propety (only ```ParameterType``` and ```UnitType```). ```ParameterElement```  derived from Elemnent and store parameter information. A ```Parameter``` class  that could be retrieved from Element represents a data value for ``ParameterElement``` and has ```StoageType```.

Comment: I have tried to map ```StoageType```  to ```ParameterType``` and discover that one and the same ```ParameterType``` could have different ```StoageType```.